# Automatically set attributes using Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model

I have some attributes, that I need to set automatically when using `create()` or `save()` methods.

### Model:

```
class SampleModel extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function setRandomColumnAttribute($value=null)
    {
        if(!is_string($hostname)){
            $value = "I set the value here";
        }

        $this->attributes['random_column'] = $value;
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
use App\SampleModel;

class SomeController extends Controller
{
    public function something()
    {
        SampleModel::create([
            'name' => 'Jeff',
        ]);

        // or instead of the above:
        // $model = new SampleModel;
        // $model->name = 'Jeff';
        // $model->save();
    }
}
```

I need to save `random_column` value, that is defined in the Model itself as you see, without passing it from the controller.

Please note if I use:

```
    SampleModel::create([
        'name'          => 'Jeff',
        'random_column' => true // or anything other than string
    ]);
```

It works and set the value, but is there any way to avoid passing this every time and just set it automatically in the Model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try observers? Add `boot()` method to your `SampleModel`:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::creating(function (SampleModel $model) {
        $model->random_column = 'Random column';
    });
}
```

Creating will trigger everytime a `->create()` is called on a `SampleModel`.

Comment: Thanks, with `$model->save()` I was having this error: `Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting! ` but now that you removed it, it works perfectly!